# Como usar el Fetch Javascript de Postman en un componente de React?

Tags: reactjs, fetch, nextjs

Pruebo una llamada en Postman y todo anda bien, extraigo el codigo para `fetch` de `JavaScript`:

```
var myHeaders = new Headers();
myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "application/json");

var raw = JSON.stringify({
  "email": "jondoe@yahoo.com"
});

var requestOptions = {
  method: 'GET',
  headers: myHeaders,
  body: raw,
  redirect: 'follow'
};

fetch("https://una-url.com", requestOptions)
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(result => console.log(result))
  .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
```

Necesito ejecutar esta llamada al montarse un componente de ruta de Next.js, entonces simplemente copio el codigo anterior dentro de

```
useEffect(() => {
  ...
}, [])
```

Y por consola el fetch, entra al Error, devolviendo:

> error TypeError: Failed to execute 'fetch' on 'Window': Request with GET/HEAD method cannot have body.

Alguien sabe que tiene de malo mi llamada? O deberia ejecutarla de otra manera?

Muchas gracias

Comment: El error te esta indicando que el método `GET` no puede tener cuerpo. Debes pasar los valores por la url. [Acá](https://www.webtips.dev/solutions/send-query-params-in-get-and-post-in-javascript) tienes unos ejemplos

Comment: Si, habia visto eso en algunas respuestas pero no terminaba de entender, armaba una url tipo ``https://miurl.com/api?email=jondoe@gmail.com`` pero lo correcto era armarlo de esta manera que me decis. No habia visto esta forma de hacerlo en otros sitios. Si queres agregalo como respuesta y la marco como aceptada. Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error se desencadena debido a que las peticiones de tipo `GET`, no pueden tener un cuerpo. Si necesitas enviar parámetros a endpoints de obtención de datos, debes pasarlos mediante la misma url.

```
const getData = async (id) => {
   const result = await fetch(
   `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/${id}`
    );
    const data = await result.json();

    return data;
};
```

Ahora si necesitas varios parámetros, podrías utilizar [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) de esta forma

```
const response = await fetch(`http://url.com?${new URLSearchParams(params)}`)
```

el parámetro *params* sería un objeto de `Javascript`

```
{
   param1: 'valorParam1',
   param2: 'valorParam2',
   ...
}
```

Lo que finalmente equivaldría a armar la url de esta manera

```
'http://url.com?param1=valorParam1&param2=valorParam2'
```

Cualquier duda nos comentas :D